# Can VPN work with current ISP?

Tags: vpn

I wanted to know that can I use VPN connection (Very High Speed > 100mbsp) over my existing ISP (4mbps with 150GB FUP)?

What will be my speed and what about Data (will it be charged from ISP?)

Comment: Before you ask why you are getting downvoted, this site is aimed at professional server administrators. This question is considered as very basic knowledge and therefor not really suited for this website.

Answer (score 1):

Well since VPN is getting encapsulated in IP packets and those IP packets will be using your ISP's line, the maximum speed and volume you will be able to use your VPN will be the limit set by your ISP. (4 mbps with 150 GB FUP)

Compare it with buying an F1 car and having to drive it on a dirt road. You CAN go 300 km/h with the car, but because your road is not suited for these speeds, you will probably go around at about 30 km/h.